# XMLHTTPRequest response doesnt contain Location field in the header

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, http-get, adblock

I was trying to modify the adblockplus code for testing purpose. I was modifying the code to send a http get request on a URL and get the final URL from the response. I tried using the below code, but the response doesn't contain the Location field in the header response. I am doing this within a firefox-extension, so I dont think cross-domain request would be any issue. Why is it that I am not able to fetch the Location field from the response? Is there a better way to accomplish this task ?

Input URL- http://netspiderads3.indiatimes.com/ads.dll/clickthrough?msid=17796167&cid=3224&slotid=1203&nsRndNo=817685688

Expected output-http://www.mensxp.com/

Actual Output- Location: null

Here is the code I am using-

```
function geturl(url){
let req= Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
req.open("GET", url);
req.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
req.send(null);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (req.readyState == 4) 
{ if (req.status == 200) 
  { try 
    {
       location = req.getResponseHeader("Location");
       console.log("Location is: " + location);
    }
    catch(e){
    console.log("Error reading the response: " + e.toString());
  }
 }
}
```

**Solution**-

I finally found the solution for this. I was not getting the final response. So I set the redirection limit to 0, now I can get the Location field in the header.
Here is what I added to my code-

```
if (request.channel instanceof Ci.nsIHttpChannel)
    request.channel.redirectionLimit = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the status code 200 mean OK, so your try block won't be executed. "Location" field only exits in redirect, which status code is 301 or 302.

That url response 302, so change `req.status == 200` to `req.status == 302`.

Comment: But status code 200 means that the request was successful, so the HTTP-response should contain a Location field even though it might not be a redirect.

Comment: No, you can use httpfox extension or command `curl -i` to check the headers.

Comment: yeah actually it is redirecting to that page, hence I am not able to fetch Location field. Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Status code 200 OK won't has the Location field. Try `curl -i http://httpbin.org/user-agent` in your terminal. Just change `200` to `302`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to check for `readyState == 2`, that is HEADERS_RECEIVED state